# Prefix for hibernate connection configurations?

Tags: java, hibernate

Does anybody know about the hibernate configurations file (hibernate.cfg.xml), what are the "connection" properties - without the "hibernate" prefix - used for?

I mean, why do those properties (such as connection.url, connection.usermame...) exist?

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        ...
        <property name="connection.url">SOME_URL</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">SOME_URL</property>
        <property name="connection.username">SOME_USER</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">SOME_USER</property>
    ...
```

Why can I use the both connection.url and hibernate.connection.url ?

ANSWER:

Ok, I believe those properties (without the hibernate. prefix) exist just for backward compatibility with configuration files of older hibernate versions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The **hibernate.connection.url** is use to connect the database url following is the configuration setting for hibernate . Hope It will help you.

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/youdb</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<mapping resource="emp/dto/Employee.hbm.xml"/>
```

Comment: Yeah, I know. Thanks. The question is - why do connection.url, connection.username, connection.password (without the hibernate. prefix) exist as well?